# Subsetting within a function with %in%

Tags: r, function, subset

I have the following dataframe.

```
head(graph_data, n = 15)
   source target
1   Ohrid СКОПЈЕ
2   Ohrid СКОПЈЕ
3   Ohrid СКОПЈЕ
4   Ohrid СКОПЈЕ
5   Ohrid СКОПЈЕ
6   Ohrid СКОПЈЕ
7   Ohrid СКОПЈЕ
8   Ohrid СКОПЈЕ
9   Ohrid СКОПЈЕ
10  Ohrid СКОПЈЕ
11  Ohrid СКОПЈЕ
12  Ohrid СКОПЈЕ
13  Ohrid СКОПЈЕ
14  Ohrid СКОПЈЕ
15  Ohrid СКОПЈЕ
```

I wrote the following function to automate the process of filtering the top number of matches with the source.

```
top_connections <- function(data, city, top_n) {
  temp <- filter(data, source == city)
  temp2 <- as.data.frame(table(temp$target))  
  temp2 <- arrange(temp2, desc(Freq))
  temp2 <- temp2[1:top_n, ]
  temp3 <- as.data.frame(unique(temp2$Var1))
  colnames(temp3)[1] <- "top_connecitons" 

  #works fine until here

  temp4 <- subset(temp, source %in% temp3[, "top_connecitons"])

   return(temp4)
}
```

The only problem I am having is to subset the temp file with the values only present in temp4.

The result is a dataframe with zero rows, while it should contain the top 15 target connections to the filtered city.

**Function call:**

```
test1 <- top_connections(graph_data, "Skopje", top_n = 15)
```

Any idea where Im getting it wrong?

Update:

**Link to data**: https://github.com/stefan-jovanovski/predictive_modeling/blob/master/graph_encoding_fixed.xlsx

**Environment:**

```
search()
 [1] ".GlobalEnv"         "package:networkD3" 
 [3] "package:data.table" "package:DT"        
 [5] "package:corrplot"   "package:scales"    
 [7] "package:dplyr"      "package:purrr"     
 [9] "package:readr"      "package:tidyr"     
[11] "package:tibble"     "package:tidyverse" 
[13] "package:ggthemes"   "package:ggplot2"   
[15] "package:readxl"     "package:lubridate" 
[17] "tools:rstudio"      "package:stats"     
[19] "package:graphics"   "package:grDevices" 
[21] "package:utils"      "package:datasets"  
[23] "package:methods"    "Autoloads"         
[25] "package:base"
```

Comment: Are you using any additional packages?

Comment: Looks like you are using functions from `dplyr`. Don't forget the `library()` call so this is clear.

Comment: In your example, 'temp3' contains variables from `data$target`. Then you compare it to `data$source`. Is it possible that `unique(data%target) != unique(data$source)`?

Comment: Please have a look on [writing reproducible examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @Istrel yes - unique(data%target) != unique(data$source). But we are not looking for equality here. We calculate the frequency of frequency of each unique modality in data$target. And, for the top "n" most frequent modalities, we subset them from data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
graph_data < data.frame(source=c("Paris","Berlin","Paris","London","Munich"),target=c("Amsterdam","Paris","Paris","Brighton","Paris"),stringsAsFactors = F)

top_connections <- function(data, city, top_n) {
  temp <- dplyr::filter(data,source==city)

  temp2 <- as.data.frame(table(temp$target))  
  temp2 <- dplyr::arrange(temp2, desc(Freq))
  temp2 <- temp2[1:top_n, ]
  temp3 <- as.data.frame(unique(temp2$Var1))
  colnames(temp3)[1] <- "top_connecitons"   
  temp4 <- subset(temp, source %in% temp3[, "top_connecitons"]) 
  return(temp4)
}
```

Give it a shot:

```
  top_connections(graph_data,"Paris",2)
  source    target
1  Paris Amsterdam
2  Paris     Paris
```

Comment: I'm still getting the same result. Zero rows. 

In any case, the problematic part is the temp4.. subset line. All results prior to that line work fine for me.

Comment: Can you post/redirect me to your data? And how do you call the function?what arguments that is

Comment: I made an update. Data/Environment/Function call included in original post. Thank you for the help.

Comment: the encoding is messed up :"1949","Skopje","���ϣ�"

Comment: I changed the file to xlsx to preserve the encoding. Should be ok now.

Comment: I found my mistake. It should be 

 temp4 <- subset(temp, target %in% temp3[, "top_connecitons"]) 

My bad. Silly mistake.

Comment: Yeah. It was returning empy dataframe as no unique values of temp3 were matching any values in source. In any case, thanks for the assitence :)